# I am trying to make a command that multiplies all the arguments

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Here is the code I have currently:

```
@client.command()
async def Q1(ctx, *args):
  Number = 1
  for arg in args:
    Number = Number * float(arg)
    await ctx.send(Number)
```

But it adds 2 0s everytime you multiple more than 2 arguments and I also want it to only print the last answer and not every argument.

Comment: Please update your question with some example inputs and the expected outputs.

Comment: Take the `await` out of the loop if you only want it done at the end.

Comment: Print `args` to see what all the arguments are, that should help explain why you're getting zeroes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're awaiting `ctx.send(Number)` on every iteration of the `for` loop.

```py
@client.command()
async def Q1(ctx, *args):
  Number = 1
  for arg in args:
    Number = Number * float(arg)
    await ctx.send(Number) # This line is inside of the loop
                           # hence running on every iteration
```

Instead, move the `await ctx.send(Number)` outside of the loop, and it will only print the final `Number` value.

```py
@client.command()
async def Q1(ctx, *args):
  Number = 1
  for arg in args:
    Number = Number * float(arg)
  await ctx.send(Number)
```

If we test this with

```py
def Q1(args):
  Number = 1
  for arg in args:
    Number = Number * float(arg)
    #await ctx.send(Number)
  print(Number)
    
Q1([ 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ])
```

it returns `720.0`. I'm assuming that by "adds 2 0s everytime you multiple more than 2 arguments," you're referring to the `.0` after the `720`. This exists because the `Number` variable is a floating point value. You can remove this by formatting `Number`.

```
@client.command()
async def Q1(ctx, *args):
  Number = 1
  for arg in args:
    Number = Number * float(arg)
  await ctx.send('{:.0f}'.format(Number))
```

This will round `Number` to zero decimal places, giving the appearance of an Integer value and returning `720` using the numbers from the previous example.

Answer (score 2):

```
async def Q1(ctx, *args):
  Number = 1
  for arg in args:
    Number = Number * float(arg)
    await ctx.send(Number)
```

I dont think you need that await in the for loop. Take it out of the loop and you should have the answer.

```
@client.command()
async def Q1(ctx, *args):
  Number = 1
  for arg in args:
    Number = Number * float(arg)
  await ctx.send(Number)
```